# using iptables to filter traffic on specific ports with multiple domains

Tags: iptables, routing

Let's imagine I own two domains:
`example1.com` and `example2.com`
and I also have a server where I have 2 Node.js webapp running:

- app1 is running on port 81 and
- app2 is running on port 82

Now both of my domains are connected to this server, meaning that if I go to
`http://example1.com:81` or to `http://example2.com:81` I'll get app1 page, and if I go to
`http://example1.com:82` or to `http://example2.com:82` I'll get app2 page.

**Now my question**: Is it possible by using iptables to block all requests from a certain domain?

If anybody requests `http://example1.com:81` they'll get the app1.
but if they request `http://example1.com:82`, they'll get no answer.

Similarly, if anybody requests `http://example2.com:82` they'll get the app2,
but if they request `http://example2.com:81` they'll get no answer.

I hope my question is clear. 
I had some difficulties to describe it in the title; I'm sorry for that.

Comment: cross-site related: https://serverfault.com/questions/361415/blocking-connection-based-on-http-header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Now my question: Is it possible by using iptables to block all requests from a certain domain?"

## No, not with firewall

Because the domain name is not part IP or TCP or anything at levels 1 -> 3.
First the client looks up the IP address from the domain name, then it communicates using the IP address.

## How to do it, a different way.

Some protocols, such as http, embed the domain name in the request. Therefore, you can put the filtering in the web-server configuration.

You could do this all off of one port if you want. Or as described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't tell IPtables to block all traffic on port 81 but accept traffic on port 81. Which is it? Accept or block? How does it know what domain they want if its blocking them? And if by some how it could know which domain they wanted then hasn't it accepted them before deciding to block them?

You will have to do what you want at the HTTP level. Assuming you are using Apache, it can be configured with virtual host containers to only listen for a specific domain on a specific port. The user's connection wont get timed out (as if blocked by IPtables) but they can be given a black page, a error message, a redirect, etc. which virtually blocks them from using that service on the wrong port.

Not sure about your project, but i think you can use Apache to forward the traffic to the `node.js`, and if you can do that, then you don't have to use different ports. Apache can accept all traffic on the same port and then proxy forward that traffic to `node1.js` or `node2.js` depending on the hostname supplied `example1.com` or `example2.com`.

Comment: thanks. i thought that it could auto refere to itself: if domain requested is domain1, then forward to port 81.